# Minha função print não funciona no prompt de comando do windows

Tags: python, windows, prompt

Eu estou começando a estudar programação. Baixei a versão 3.8.3 do Python e para escrever os programas baixei o Sublime text que permite executar os programas na própria plataforma.

Quando comecei estava funcionando normalmente, conseguia rodar os programas tanto no Sublime text quanto no prompt do Windows (tenho o Windows 10), mas fiquei um tempo sem estudar e quando fui voltar agora a função print não funciona através do prompt, apenas através do Sublime text. Quando tento rodar pelo prompt a janela abre e fecha muito rapidamente, o que não acontecia antes.

O estranho é que minha namorada me enviou um programa por email e o programa que ela fez roda tranquilamente pelo prompt do Windows, mas os que eu faço no meu computador não.

Já tentei ver se era erro de digitação, então escrevi um programa bem simples:

> print ("Ola mundo")

E mesmo assim não funcionou.

Já desinstalei e instalei o Python e nada. Tentei escrever o programa usando outra ferramenta de texto e não funcionou também. Vi que podia olhar no help() do Python para ver se estava tudo certo e está.

Será que é algum problema com o Windows?

Comment: Durante a instalação do `Python` (site oficial) o instalador pergunta se desejas `criar` a variável de ambiente do Python. Caso esteja desabilitando esta opção durante a instalação, o Python não será `reconhecido` no `prompt de comandos`. Sugiro reinstalar o Python `habilitando` a definição da `variável de ambiente`.

Comment: Outra coisa, é bom saber que `atualmente` existe em funcionamento duas versões de Python incompatíveis entre si. A versão `2` e a versão `3`. Isto significa dizer que, programas criados em `Python 3` não serão executados por interpretadores de versão `2` ou vise-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Como exatamente você está executando o programa? (Não posso deixar comentário pois não tenho pontuação o suficiente).

Primeiro você deve se certificar de que a instalação do Python está ok na sua máquina rodando `python --version` no seu terminal. Se mostrar a versão certinho, é pq está ok. Se não reconhecer o comando você deve refazer a instalação.

Uma vez que a instalação esteja correta, execute o comando `python`, isso te colocará dentro do interpretador Python. Lá você poderá executar vários comandos individualmente, inclusive o `print("Hello, world!")`.

Para executar um programa que você tem em um arquivo, rode no terminal o comando `python nomeDoArQuivo`. Certifique-se de que o arquivo tem extensão .py, e que você está rodando o comando no mesmo diretório em que se encontra o arquivo. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Só para complementar sua resposta, é bom perceber que, durante a instalação do `Python` (site oficial) o instalador pergunta se desejas `criar` a variável de ambiente do Python. Caso esteja desabilitando esta opção durante a instalação, o Python não será `reconhecido` no `prompt de comandos`. Sugiro reinstalar o Python `habilitando` a definição da `variável de ambiente`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa noite!

Funcionou rodar o comando ***python Nome do arquivo***.

Muito obrigado pela resposta!